# adding noise to recovery dynamics in coupled nonlinear ode

Tags: matlab, ode, noise

I would like to add noise to a nonlinear coupled ODE system (the Fitzhugh-Nagumo model). I added gaussian white noise to the input (see code: adding noise to \dot(V), which is the voltage dynamics) and I would like to get similar `jagged' spikes when I add noise to the recovery variable (\dot(w)).

However, I use more or less the same procedure for adding noise to the recovery variable, although I had to decrease the sigma. As a result, I do get a variable outcome, but not the `jagged' spikes as I would like to see. So far, I haven't been able to find out how to rescale the system so that I get a similar simulation with noise for the voltage dynamics and the recovery dynamics.

Code for adding Gaussian white noise to voltage dynamics (difference between code is `sigma' and where the noise is added in the Forward Euler):

```
%% Parameters
%Time vector for integration
dt = 0.1;
tend = (3/1e-2); %make sure to capture some spikes
t = 0:dt:tend;

%simulations
nsimu = 20;

%Initial values
V0 = -1.5;
w0 = -3/8;

%initial values vectors
V = zeros(1, length(t));
V(1) = V0;
w = zeros(1, length(t));
w(1) = w0;

%input
Iapp = 0.3303;

%noise
sigma = 1.0;
nsimu = 50;
eta = zeros(1,length(t));


%% Functions
dV = @(t, V, w) V - V^3/3 - w + Iapp;
dw = @(t, V, w) 0.08*(V + 0.7 - 0.8* w);

%% Adding white noise on input

for m = 1:nsimu

    %Generate noise vector
    for i = 1:length(t)-1
        eta(i+1) = eta(i) + sigma*sqrt(dt)*randn;
    end

    %Forward Euler + white noise
    for ii = 1:length(eta)-1
        w(ii+1) = w(ii) + dt * dw(t, V(ii), w(ii)); 
        V(ii+1) = V(ii) + dt * dV(t, V(ii), w(ii)) + dt*eta(ii);
    end

    plot(t, V, 'k-', 'LineWidth', 1.5)
    drawnow

end
```

Code for adding noise to the recovery variable `w'. (Fairly similar to previous code ... but it needs work)

```
%% Parameters
%Time vector for integration
dt = 0.1;
tend = (3/1e-2); %make sure to capture some spikes
t = 0:dt:tend;

%simulations
nsimu = 20;

%Initial values
V0 = -1.5;
w0 = -3/8;

%initial values vectors
V = zeros(1, length(t));
V(1) = V0;
w = zeros(1, length(t));
w(1) = w0;

%input
Iapp = 0.3303;

%noise
sigma = 1e-3;
nsimu = 50;
eta = zeros(1,length(t));


%% Functions
dV = @(t, V, w) V - V^3/3 - w + Iapp;
dw = @(t, V, w) 0.08*(V + 0.7 - 0.8* w);

%% Adding white noise on input

for m = 1:nsimu

    %Generate noise vector
    for i = 1:length(t)-1
        eta(i+1) = eta(i) + sigma*sqrt(dt)*randn;
    end

    %Forward Euler + white noise
    for ii = 1:length(eta)-1
        w(ii+1) = w(ii) + dt * dw(t, V(ii), w(ii)) + dt*eta(ii); 
        V(ii+1) = V(ii) + dt * dV(t, V(ii), w(ii));
    end

    plot(t, V, 'k-', 'LineWidth', 1.5)
    drawnow

end
```

The outcome of both codes should be a perturbed simulation of the dynamics of the system. The simulation of noise on `w' should appear the same as the simulation of noise on`V'.

Comment: Instead of adding `dt*eta(ii)`, add `(eta(ii+1)-eta(ii))` as the formula `dw=a(t,V,w)*dt + sigma*dB` in the Ito formalism demands. Of course what you do is also correct, but uses an integrated random walk, which is a differentiable function.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This works for both the voltage dynamics and the recovery dynamics. The voltage dynamics looks really good now. The recovery dynamics is at another time scale (it's slower than the voltage dynamics), which is why I multiply the noise with `(dt/0.08)* eta(ii+1) - eta(ii)` and add it in the Forward Euler step 
```
    for ii = 1:length(eta)-1
        w(ii+1) = w(ii) + dt * dw(t, V(ii), w(ii)) + (dt/0.08)* eta(ii+1) - eta(ii); 
        V(ii+1) = V(ii) + dt * dV(t, V(ii), w(ii));
    end
```
 Is this correct? Can I do this?